# Protractor: How to select the content inside table cols, and save it to json file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, gulp-protractor

I have a html content which I am testing using protractor, I have to save the text `"ABCDEF"` which is present in below code/table.

```
<td data-th="Confirmation Number">
<span class="bt-content">
    <a href="any_link">ABCDEF
    </a>
    </span>
</td>
```

I have tried to see take snapshot of the page, but still i want get the data from this code and save it to json file
Any help would be appreciated Thank you!
Anybody can help??

Comment: get the text by `bt-content` -> `a`

Comment: Thanks @FCin , But bt-content is not a unique identifier in my page

Comment: find using CSS 'a[href^="any_link"]'

Comment: If you cannot distinguish elements on a page then it is very difficult to get the element you want. One way would be to get it by surrounding elements., e.g.: `element(by.tagName('span')).element(by.tagName('a')).getText()`. Although, the best thing here would be to add `id` for `a` tag.

Comment: thanks @Oleksii and FCIn, let me try out of these ^^